# Hyper-V, Domain Controllers, and System Center Virtual Machine Manager R2 (SCVMM)

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, domain-controller, hyper-v-server-2008-r2, scvmm

I'm trying to add one of my Hyper-V Hosts (Windows Server 2008 R2), which is also my domain controller, to the SCVMM console so that I can manage it and its guest VM's from there.  When adding it to the console I get an error message that states:

Error (2912)
An internal error has occurred trying to contact an agent on the myserver.domain.local server. 
 (Cannot perform this operation on built-in accounts (0x8007055B))

Recommended Action
Ensure the agent is installed and running. Ensure the WS-Management service is installed and running, then restart the agent.

I have done what this error message suggests, but I am still having issues. Any ideas on how to get around this?  Could it be that the server running Hyper-V is also a domain controller?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Why aren't you virtualizing your domain controller? Microsoft gives you the license for the virtual server provided your physical server is just doing Hyper V. There may be hacks to get the DC added, but it's so easy to just get it done right. Create a new VM. Promote it to domain controller. Demote the Hyper V server. Add the server to SCVMM.

Comment: +1 MS's official stance is that Hyper-V servers should not be DCs; while it works for basic configurations, it breaks things (lots of things) like SCVMM.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this before as well and found big issues trying to add the Hyper-V host (which is also a DC) to SCVMM.

The error pretty much covers the problem, SCVMM is trying to do something with the host's local accounts (use one, add one, change logon rights....not sure what) but as it is a DC it doesn't have any local users in the same way a member server would.

My solution was to use another machine for a host.

I suppose you could create a new DC, dc unpromo the current DC, add it to SCVMM etc etc.

The easier/safer approach would be to just use another box for Hyper-V and move the current VMs from the DC over to it.

Colin.